# After adding elasticsearch support, Spring Boot complain BeanCreationException with nested IllegalStateException No association found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have run into a strange problem. I created a project with Spring Boot 2.0.1 with `redis`, `mongodb` and `elasticsearch` . Before adding elasticsearch, everything runs smoothly, but after I add elasticsearch, Spring Boot starts complaining，but the error looks like not related to elasticsearch, it complains that it could not create `userRepo` 。 Please get noticed I used lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to generate constructor to make injection work, so it should not be `@autowired` issue, Anyone can help me out? thank in adavance

```
2018-05-02 16:12:58.687  INFO 74244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-05-02 16:12:59.037  WARN 74244 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [/Users/wangpeng/workspace/books/gtm/backend/api/out/production/classes/dev/local/gtm/api/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/wangpeng/workspace/books/gtm/backend/api/out/production/classes/dev/local/gtm/api/security/UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No association found!
2018-05-02 16:12:59.037 DEBUG 74244 --- [  restartedMain] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection manager is shutting down
2018-05-02 16:12:59.037 DEBUG 74244 --- [  restartedMain] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection manager shut down

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my subproject's `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties as Map<String, ?>
}
test {
    systemProperties['spring.profiles.active'] = 'test'
}
dependencies {
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springFoxVersion}")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:${springFoxVersion}")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springFoxVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.20.1")
    implementation("org.redisson:redisson:${redissonVersion}")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")
    implementation("com.github.vanroy:spring-boot-starter-data-jest:3.1.2.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

The `UserRepo` is as follows

```
package dev.local.gtm.api.repository;

import dev.local.gtm.api.domain.User;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    String USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE = "usersByLogin";

    String USERS_BY_MOBILE_CACHE = "usersByMobile";

    String USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE = "usersByEmail";

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = USERS_BY_MOBILE_CACHE)
    Optional<User> findOneByMobile(@Param("mobile") String mobile);

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE)
    Optional<User> findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(@Param("email") String email);

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE)
    Optional<User> findOneByLogin(@Param("login") String login);

    Page<User> findAllByLoginNot(Pageable pageable, @Param("login") String login);

    List<User> findAllByActivatedIsFalseAndCreatedDateBefore(Instant dateTime);
}
```

The Spring Security Configuration is as follows:

```
package dev.local.gtm.api.config;

import dev.local.gtm.api.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import dev.local.gtm.api.security.jwt.JWTConfigurer;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "dev.local.gtm.api")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    private final JWTConfigurer jwtConfigurer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("安全配置失败", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
                .antMatchers("/content/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
                .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                        .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .apply(jwtConfigurer);
    }
}
```

The UserDetailServiceImpl is as follows:

```
package dev.local.gtm.api.security;

import dev.local.gtm.api.config.Constants;
import dev.local.gtm.api.domain.User;
import dev.local.gtm.api.repository.UserRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import lombok.val;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.hv.EmailValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("正在对用户名为 {} 的用户进行鉴权", login);

        if (new EmailValidator().isValid(login, null)) {
            val userByEmailFromDatabase = userRepo.findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(login);
            return userByEmailFromDatabase.map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(login, user))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("系统中不存在 email 为 " + login + " 的用户"));
        }

        if (Pattern.matches(Constants.MOBILE_REGEX, login)) {
            val userByMobileFromDatabase = userRepo.findOneByMobile(login);
            return userByMobileFromDatabase.map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(login, user))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("系统中不存在手机号为 " + login + " 的用户"));
        }

        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        val userByLoginFromDatabase = userRepo.findOneByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
        return userByLoginFromDatabase.map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(lowercaseLogin, user))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database"));

    }


    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {
        if (!user.isActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("用户 " + lowercaseLogin + " 没有激活");
        }
        val grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

[update] After I change `spring-boot-jest` to `spring-boot-elasticsearch` the error is more specific. it now says the `elasticsearchTemplate` bean is not defined, but in fact it is.

```
2018-05-02 17:04:59.776  WARN 76262 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [/Users/wangpeng/workspace/books/gtm/backend/api/out/production/classes/dev/local/gtm/api/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [/Users/wangpeng/workspace/books/gtm/backend/api/out/production/classes/dev/local/gtm/api/security/UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' available
2018-05-02 17:04:59.805  INFO 76262 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-05-02 17:04:59.822  INFO 76262 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-02 17:04:59.925 ERROR 76262 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in dev.local.gtm.api.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The bean is defined in `ElasticConfig` as follows

```
package dev.local.gtm.api.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.EntityMapper;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes")
public class ElasticConfig {
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()));
    }

    public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        }

        @Override
        public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I reuse same entities for both Elasticsearch and MongoDB, which raise the exception. So I managed to get it resolved by separating the entities